# Ramda > Mongoose > Data Structure Manipulation

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ramda.js

I have a model that looks like this

```
var TermSchema = new Schema({
group: {type:String},
key: {type:String},
translations:[{
  clientId:{type:Number,default:config.gdgId},
  lang:{type:String},
  val:{type:String},
  needsTrans:{type:Boolean,default:false}
}],
updatedAt:{type:Date, default: Date.now},
updatedBy:{type:String, default: ''},
createdBy:{type:String, default: ''},
createdAt:{type:String, default: Date.now},
comments:{type:String, default: ''},
softDelete:{type:Boolean,default: false}
```

});

But I need to convert the instances of a particular client's translations to the i18n format of lang > group > key > translation. My original code looked like this

```
function companyTerms(clientId){
var deferred = q.defer();
var companyObj = {'en-US':{},'de-DE':{},'en-GB':{},'es-SP':{},'fr-FR':{},'it-IT':{},'nl-NL':{},'pt-BR':{},'zh-CN':{}};
Term.find({'translations':{$elemMatch:{'clientId':clientId}}, 'softDelete': false}, function(err,terms){
    _.each(terms,function(term){
      _.each(term.translations,function(trans){
        if(companyObj[trans.lang]){
          companyObj[trans.lang][term.group] = {};
        }
      })
    })
    _.each(terms,function(term){
      _.each(term.translations,function(trans){
        if (trans.clientId == clientId && companyObj[trans.lang]) {
          companyObj[trans.lang][term.group][term.key] = trans.val;
        }
      })
    })
    deferred.resolve(companyObj);
  })
  return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Gross I know!

So I was looking for ways to clean up this code/speed up the response. My first attempt was to use the Ramda library with a helper function.

```
function addToLang(groupObject){
let mapValues = obj => {
  obj['group'] = groupObject['group']
  obj['key'] = groupObject['key']
  return obj
  }
  return R.map(mapValues, groupObject.translations)
```

}

```
function companyTerms(clientId){
 return Term.find({'translations':{$elemMatch:{'clientId':clientId}},  'softDelete': false})
  .then(R.map(R.pick(['group','translations','key'])))
  .then(R.map(addToLang))//Adds group field to each translation object
  .then(R.flatten())//Flattens the different key objects
  .then(R.filter(R.propEq('clientId',parseInt(clientId))))//Filters out non-client translations
  .then(R.groupBy(R.prop('lang')))//Groups by language
  .then(R.map(R.groupBy(R.prop('group'))))//Sub-groups by group
  .then(R.map(R.map(R.groupBy(R.prop('key')))))//Has key as final group-value
  .then(R.map(R.map(R.map(R.pick(['key'])))))//Removes all other meta-data
}
```

But I was annoyed by the helper function and decided to just jump into the 'aggregate' constructor and my final code looked like this.

```
  function companyTerms(clientId){
return Term.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind":"$translations"
  },{
    "$match":{
      "translations.clientId":parseInt(clientId),
      "softDelete":false
    }
  },{
    "$project":{
      key:"$key",
      group:"$group",
      lang:'$translations.lang',
    }
  }])
  .then(R.groupBy(R.prop('lang')))//Groups by language
  .then(R.map(R.groupBy(R.prop('group'))))//Sub-groups by group
  .then(R.map(R.map(R.groupBy(R.prop('key')))))//Has key as final group-value
  .then(R.map(R.map(R.map(R.pick(['key'])))))//Removes all other meta-data
};
```

This wasn't much more concise than before but it is much faster than before.

Comment: Was there a question here?

Comment: My general Idea was to solicit ideas for making this function more concise

Comment: You should probably make that more clear in the question.  You should be able to edit it to add an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities:

- If you're worried about that helper, because it doesn't fit with the rest of the code, this looks (from the perspective of one without any data to test with) like a points-free alternative:

  ```
  R.lift(R.map)(R.compose(R.merge, R.pick(['group', 'key'])), R.prop('translations'))
  ```
- You probably don't need all those `then`s.  It doesn't look like there's anything asynchronous after the first call.  While it's often convenient to just chain `then`s together, it starts to lose its luster as the lists grow longer.

  You might simply `pipe` the functions together and call the combination inside a single `then`.  The point is that as long as `f1`, `f2`, ... `fn` are all synchronous, then these are equivalent:

  ```
  someAsyncFn()
    .then(f1)
    .then(f2)
    .then(f3)
    .then(f4)
  ```

  and

  ```
  someAsyncFn().then(pipe(f1, f2, f3, f4))
  ```

Neither of these is earth-shattering, but either might help clean up your code.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I'll give it a go!